Why the output result quality is gradually reduced for local ollama
Background:
I want to utilize langchain and Ollama to translate several unstructured txt documents (size ranges from 20 kb to 200 kb) into structured Markdown format.
What I observed is that, the first document output from Ollama (using llama3.1 8b) has the best quality while the quality of the results gradually reduce for the following runs and the llm starts to output summaries or dummy messages which I don't want.
Does anyone know the reason and how to fix this issue?
Code
llm = ollama.Ollama(model=_model,temperature=0.1, top_k=10, top_p=0.5, 
num_ctx=12288,mirostat_tau=3)

prompt_message = [
("system", '''You are an experienced markdown document engineer and you are requested to
format the provided document to structural markdown format and clean the document 
such that it only contains valid bylaw clauses. 
 
Please strictly following the rules below while formatting the document:
* Only contain the clauses without any other information, interpretation or summary.
* The clause content should be exact the same as the original document with no altering of the content
* Categorize the clauses based on the bylaw type. 
* Remove any unnecessary information such as headers, footers, and any other irrelevant information. 
* The document should be structured in a way that it is easy to read and understand.
* If the content is considered as a table, format the data into a markdown table.
 '''),
 
("human", "Generate result based on the document: {document}")]

txt_content_template = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(prompt_message)
txt_struct_chain = (
        txt_content_template | llm | StrOutputParser()
    )

for _txt in _txtpool:
    structure_result = txt_struct_chain.invoke({"document": _txt })
    

